# Implementation of projections in event-sourced system

Tags: architecture, cqrs, event-sourcing, complexity, message-queue

I'm working on a application which uses event-sourcing and CQRS to define it's domain model.

**Background**

We have implemented projections to aggregate stream of all domain events into a read models used by the application. But I think our current implementation is quirky and finicky as we tinker with it frequently. So I was thinking if there are any alternatives of projection implementations.

Currently our architecture is SQL database with custom layer to store events and handle the projection event loading. We have two types of projections, local and global.

**Current requirements**

Local projections store model in memory, so each service instance has it's own copy. This also requires all events to be reloaded after each restart. And as the amount of events grows this takes longer and longer. We did some optimizations for some projections to not need whole event store, but it is not total solution. We like these projections as they are easy to implement and allow experimentation before the read model is stabilized.

Global projections/processors are shared across all service instances. Our architecture handles tracking processed events throuth locks stored in database. This way, event is processed only once. These projections can either update a specific table containing the model. Or it can run something like document generation or file upload for each event. Global projections are good because they are fast, but they take more effort to implement and are harder to change. They also take an hour to build from scratch due to loading, and processing of all events and updating database frequently during rebuilding.

There are also problems of dependencies between projections. We are beginning to realize it would be great if processing of one projection could depend on another projection. Maybe one projection sending events to another projection with those events not being domain events? Or process waiting for a projection to process specific events. Right now, our current implementation doesn't feel stable or extensible enough.

**How we got here**

All of our projections started as in-memory local projections. This allowed us to quickly roll out our service and made it easy and quick to fix the projections. But as amount of events increased, the startup time also increased due to all projections needing to process all the events. We solved that by either extending the projections to only load only some amount of latest events and making them robust against missing events. Or by rewriting them as persistent global projections, which was mostly straightforward but made subsequent modifications more difficult. That is because it requires changes to database schema and rebuilding of the changed global projection on startup, which takes time. It is also complicated by both versions of the projection needing to coexist as old one is still used when new one is being rebuilt.

**The problem**

I would be surprised if these problems aren't shared by many who implement projections in event-sourced projects, but I'm having hard time finding concrete implementation of production projections. Most I find are sample projects used to demonstrate CQRS with minimal concerns for ease of development, performance or memory consumption.

I've looked at event-store databases like Event Store, and that is useful for storing and querying of events. It does provide event streaming feature, but that is not durable and doesn't track multiple clients and what they processed.

So I've looked at message brokers like Kafka, RabbitMQ or ActiveMQ, and they do provide easy ways to deal with multiple consumers, which would be the projections and would handle both local and global projections. But they do not store all the events. This causes problems because replay of all events is something needed for both local projections and for new or updated global projections. I was thinking about implementing custom reload-all-events logic, but that feels like just different kind of complexity.

This then makes me wonder how others handle these kind of problems? Maybe there is library, framework or system that could simplify implementation of projections or processors in both local and global configurations and handle both storing of events and coordinating processing of those events across multiple running services. But I'm not aware of such a thing.

Comment: No incremental/periodic snapshots?

Comment: @ShadowsInRain We found snapshots not that useful in our use cases. Either local projection can load only some latest events. Or the state is too big and projection's model needs to be persisted into table.

Comment: Found [this article](https://domaincentric.net/blog/event-sourcing-projections), which states something which looks pretty obvious to me *"in memory projections [..] work well for prototyping, when the number of events is fairly small"*. For any real system, each projection must be stored/persisted somewhere (at least snapshot-wise), otherwise you are doing [Shlemiel's painting algorithm](https://wiki.c2.com/?ShlemielThePainter)

Comment: @DocBrown Yeah. We expect most of our projections to become persisten ones. But that doesn't remove need for full eventstore replay for in-memory projections used in debugging and prototyping and new/updated persistent projections.

Comment: @Euphoric: whatever projection you are going to implement (regardless of in-memory, debugging, prototyping or production), you need some kind of baseline for it, probably generated from the "read model". Otherwise you cannot avoid performance degradation to the point where the system becomes unusable.

Comment: @DocBrown Thanks for pointing that out. My concern is less about performance/memory and more about how to implement architecture/infrastructure for dealing with all the requirements around the projections. For example, I wouldn't like it if the infrastructure made in-memory projections impossible or hard to implement.

Comment: So you're rather looking for a vocabulary/workflow to express projections tersely? After re-reading the question few times, I still have an impression that performance is the crux. Also, the long wind-up time of a persisted projection tells me that it wasn't implemented incrementally. Or maybe that's because you're excluding the projection from the deployment data. (See, I am being distracted by the performance again. Could you edit the question to make it more focused?)

Comment: @ShadowsInRain It would be amazing if there was terse way to express projections. But that is I think different topic. What do you mean by "implemented incrementally" or including projection in deployment data? I might try to refocus the question, but I'm not sure if I can as I think the focus is already good enough.

Comment: @ShadowsInRain I did add some more background. But I need some more time to rethink the question if I'm to reformulate it. I don't think this is a simple topic as I need to make all requirements clear in why we care about them.  I do agree that performance and memory is important feature. But so is ease of implementation and modification.

Comment: @Euphoric When doing snapshots incrementally, there is a way to know which events are included in the snapshots already and which aren't yet. This way you can quickly rebuild from the current snapshot and the remaining (unconsumed) events. It also allows to build the snapshot asynchronously in the background. But to fully benefit from that process you'll have to actually persist the snapshot — I've seen people assuming any sort of projection must be ephemeral and thus can be discarded during the deployment.

Comment: @ShadowsInRain Of course me and my team understand all of those. I just don't see how it is going to make things simple. Again, my problem is not about specific performance optimizations. My problem is about complexity of implementing infrastructure around things like snapshots, reloading events from history and synchronizing multiple event consumers across service instances. Best option would be to use 3rd party library or framework. Or in case of custom implementation, what would be least complex and most stable architecture given our requirements.

Comment: @Euphoric Right. I also see you've added a point about migrations, that makes the picture a little clearer. I guess the ES library landscape is barren because in the end it boils down to tracking and polling/messaging, which is simple, and the "reduction" rules, which cannot be abstracted anyway. That's how I do it, but I did not find it particularly inconvenient. Perhaps you could show the code (or other parts of the workflow) that you find the most mind-numbing or painful.

Comment: Mabe you will have to create your own framework which fits to your existing infrastructure?